# Can a non-editable NSTextView highlight links using setAutomaticLinkDetectionEnabled?

Tags: cocoa, url, hyperlink, nstextview

I've been using a NSTextView to display some non-editable text and would like to highlight any links within it's string. I've seen some code that parses out the links and adds attributes. That would work fine, but I was wondering if I could somehow reuse the built-in link detection somehow.

I've tried setting:

```
[textView setEnabledTextCheckingTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink];
[textView setAutomaticLinkDetectionEnabled:YES];
```

and using:

```
[textView checkTextInDocument:nil];
```

after setting the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, here is how I've manually added links to a NSTextView:

```
- (void)highlightLinksInTextView:(NSTextView *)view {
  NSDataDetector *linkDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
  NSArray *matches = [linkDetector matchesInString:view.string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, view.string.length)];

  [view.textStorage beginEditing];

  for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    if (!match.URL) continue;

    NSDictionary *linkAttributes = @{
      NSLinkAttributeName: match.URL,
    };

    [view.textStorage addAttributes:linkAttributes range:match.range];
  }

  [view.textStorage endEditing];
}
```

Unfortunately you have to call this every time you set the NSTextView string.

Answer (score 1):

I recently stumbled upon this and created an NSTextView subclass, [LinkDetectingTextView.swift](https://gist.github.com/martinhoeller/c4372ec33b4352115f34d92b359286aa). Hope this helps someone in the future.